# libxml xmlNodePtr to raw xml string?

Tags: c, libxml2

Given a valid, arbitrary xmlNodePtr, I would like the string representation of that node, including the tag, attributes, and children in the same form (recursive).

FWIW, my scenario is I am using PerformXPathQuery to get a block of data from within an existing document. I need to get the results of the query, which has nested XML elements in it, as the raw string, so I can insert it into a text field.

These seems like a simple task, however I cannot find an easy way. Writing an xmlDocPtr to file must do this, however, I cannot see a handy method that will do the same thing to an arbitrary node in the tree, and return it in memory.

I hope I am just going blind from the brown-on-brown documentation color scheme at xmlsoft.org

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is [xmlNodeDump](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeDump) (or [xmlNodeDumpOutput](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeDumpOutput)) what you are looking for?

Comment: Was looking for this quite a while and couldn't get it to work. My returned size had been `-1` and my buffer was `NULL`. Just for anyone as an info: Initialize your buffer! Some examples in the internet are just not correct and the docs are not very detailed in this point either. Use `xmlBufferPtr buffer = xmlBufferCreate();`.

Answer (score 9):

My code I used to dump a node to a string. It's objectiv-c so just change your output as needed.

```
xmlBufferPtr buffer = xmlBufferCreate();
int size = xmlNodeDump(buffer, myXMLDoc, myXMLNode, 0, 1);

NSLog(@"%d", size);
NSLog(@"%s", buffer->content);
```

Don't forget to free your buffer again.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it definitely is to create a new document, then use `xmlDocCopyNode` to copy the node into it and serialize it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Including the leading <xml> tag is definitely sub-optimal. However I tried it with the following and the copy comes up empty : `<code> 
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < nodes->nodeNr; i++) { 
xmlDocPtr partialDoc = xmlNewDoc(BAD_CAST XML_DEFAULT_VERSION); 
xmlChar *mem; 
int len; 
xmlNodePtr copyNode = xmlDocCopyNode( nodes->nodeTab[i], partialDoc, 1 );
xmlAddChild( xmlDocGetRootElement( partialDoc ), copyNode );
xmlDocDumpMemory( partialDoc, &mem, &len ); NSLog( @"%s", mem ); 
}
</code>`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand if you still have a problem or not. Could you update your question if you have something unclear so far?