# libxml2 convert a node and all it's contents to a raw xml string

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I would like to convert a node and all it's content and children to a string.

for example I have this node

```
<node i="a">
  <child1>azerty</child1>
  <child2>qwerty</child2>
</node>
```

I would like to have function to translate to a string "str1"
the content of the string will be like this:

```
<node i="a">
  <child1>azerty</child1>
  <child2>qwerty</child2>
</node>
```

That is the raw node contents in the exact shape it was in the source xml file.

Comment: Please correct the mistake in the question. Same xml code is given twice, but no desired string.

Comment: it is not a mistake -_-'

Comment: I edited your question to make it clear that you want the raw xml contents. Is your question answered correctly here: [libxml xmlNodePtr to raw xml string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232094/libxml-xmlnodeptr-to-raw-xml-string)? It's easy to find it: `[libxml2] raw`.

Answer (score 0):

this might help:

`xmlChar *  xmlXPathCastNodeSetToString (xmlNodeSetPtr ns)`
Converts a node-set to its string value.

from [the documentation](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpath.html)

Comment: I have already tried it. It only converts the content in my example the result will be:
"azerty\nqwerty"