# XPath for xml:lang? Testing attribute self axis fails

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

The context is a XSLT identity transformation with

```
<xsl:template match="abstract[@xml:lang]">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(self::xml:lang)]|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

so, I expected to remove the attribute `xml:lang`.

Comment: So what? What happened then? Can you give a [little more context please](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? A sample input XML, a complete stylesheet, the output and explaining what's wrong with it would be a good start.

Comment: @MathiasMüller, I agree, but the answers was so fast and the "openess" was good for 3 excelent and different answers. See my comments at  JLRishe's, the best explanation for context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have seen a warning along the lines of the following:

> Warning! The self axis will never select any element nodes when
>   starting at an attribute node

You could instead test the attribute's `name()`:

```
  <xsl:template match="abstract[@xml:lang]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name() != 'xml:lang']|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

This will effectively delete the `xml:lang` attribute from `abstract` as requested.

Comment: Where would OP have seen that warning?

Comment: @JLRishe: That particular warning is emitted by SaxonHE9-5-1-2J for OP's template.

Comment: Ah. I don't see any mention of OP using Saxon, but perhaps OP has mentioned using it in the past?

Comment: @JLRishe: Sorry if my brevity misled.  Merely meant that **ideally** OP *should have seen a warning along the lines of the following* (message provided by Saxon).

Comment: I see. I don't know if most XSLT processors provide warnings for potentially useless XPaths. .NET's XSLT processor sure doesn't, but thank you for clarifying nonetheless.

Comment: @JLRishe: Using [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/products/products.xml) is like including a little piece of Michael Kay in one's XSLT edit-run-debug cycle.  Recommended.   ;-)

Comment: Thanks!  Was difficult to click on "accept" here, see my comment at @JLRishe's answer.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>There will never be an attribute on the self axis (unless you're using the libxslt processor...).</strike>
*see discussion in comments bellow*

Why don't you do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="abstract/@xml:lang"/>
```

to suppress the unwanted attribute *specifically*?

---

Working demo:  http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaFp

Comment: make sense, but this technic only works for elements, not for attribute nodes. Test by your self...

Comment: An attribute can be on the self axis. `self::node()` applied to an attribute returns the attribute (but `self::*` doesn't).

Comment: @PeterKrauss I test my answers **before** I post them. I have posted this comment before, along with a link to a demo that shows my answer working. Unfortunately there are people here that see fit to remove my comments without rhyme or reason.

Comment: @nwellnhof "*node() matches any node other than an attribute node and the root node*" http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#patterns

Comment: That's because `node()` is equivalent to `child::node()`, not `self::node()`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The text you quoted is referring to the case where `node()` is the entire pattern (and it's in a section about pattern matching, not about XPath in general). `self::node()` is something else.

Comment: @nwellnhof I am afraid  I don't see what difference it makes.

Comment: @JLRishe If `child::node()` is not supposed to include attributes, but `self::node()` is, then something's wrong with this world.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Why? There was a design decision at some point that attributes are not "children" and therefore are never on the `child::` axis. Perhaps you can take issue with `child::node()` not matching attributes, but I see nothing wrong with attributes being on the `self::` axis w.r.t. themselves.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Most notably, the XPath spec contains this text _"A location step of . is short for self::node()."_ Surely, you would agree that `.` can refer to an attribute? Also _"the self axis contains just the context node itself"_ and _"A node test node() is true for any node of any type whatsoever."_ It's quite clear from all of this that both `self::` and `node()` can refer to attributes. I have upvoted your answer because I think it's the best solution in this case, but please correct that first sentence. It is incorrect.

Comment: @JLRishe When I wrote my reply, I was relying on the following quote from Jeni Tennison: "*It's only with attributes and namespace nodes that **you can't use the self:: axis because they're only accessible through the attribute:: and namespace:: axes.***" Now I see that on the same page*, the same Jeni Tennison says: "*You can tell that the node() node test matches attributes because the expression ".", which expands to the expression "self::node()", can be used to select attributes. Unlike the child axis, the self axis selects the context node no matter what its type.*" ...

Comment: .... IMHO, expressions like node(), text(), etc. should not change their meaning when placed on a different axis - but I didn't write the specs. ---  (*) http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/nodetest.html

Comment: @michael.hor257k `node()` and `text()` don't change their meaning. The problem is that when an axis is unspecified, the default axis is `child::` and attributes are not on the child axis. As I've already said, if anything, your beef is with the confusing (but still well-defined) behavior of the `child::` axis. Luckily, the XPath spec is not subject to your opinion, so could you correct your answer (pretty please?).

Comment: Sorry @michael.hor257k, I mistook, with [this other case, for replace attribute value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24899992/287948).  Your solution is correct for XSLTv1 (!). It is a valid solution when the problem is really only to remove attribute.

Comment: @PeterKrauss I believe my solution is equally valid for XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0. Is there a reason why you are not accepting my answer (or any answer), here and in the other thread?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that `self::[QName]` can only refer to an *element*, not an attribute<sup>1</sup>.

I think michael.hor257k's suggestion is the best for this particular case, and checking the name as in kjhughes' answer should be ok in this particular case because it is about the `xml` namespace, which is unambiguous.

But in general, if you wanted to exclude a single attribute without relying on `name()`, you can do this:

```
<xsl:template match="abstract[@xml:lang]">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[(. | ../@xml:lang)[2]]|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaFp/2

This will only work correctly if the `xml:lang` attribute is present, but your pattern in the `match` attribute here ensures that it is indeed present.

---

1. Here is the relevant text from the XPath spec that explains why this is true:

> Every axis has a principal node type. If an axis can contain elements, then the principal node type is element; otherwise, it is the type of the nodes that the axis can contain. Thus,
>
> - For the attribute axis, the principal node type is attribute.
> - For the namespace axis, the principal node type is namespace.
> - For other axes, the principal node type is element.
>
> A node test that is a QName is true if and only if the type of the node (see [5 Data Model]) is the principal node type and has an expanded-name equal to the expanded-name specified by the QName. For example, child::para selects the para element children of the context node; if the context node has no para children, it will select an empty set of nodes. attribute::href selects the href attribute of the context node; if the context node has no href attribute, it will select an empty set of nodes.

The principal node type of `self::` is element, so if it is followed by a QName (such as `xml:lang`), then `self::xml:lang` can only refer to an element, not an attribute.

Comment: Thanks, you explained the point of the question (!). By other hand, the simplest solution and explanaition was @kjhughes's: in my opinion `@*[(. | ../@xml:lang)[2]]|node()` is somewhat "encryptic" when comparated with (more friendly syntax) `@*[name() != 'xml:lang']|node()`. So you show the best explanation (with the good and relevant [w3.org/TR/xpath v1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) citation!), kjhughes's the first and complete solution, and michael.hor257k the simplest alternative (not good for me but very good for other readers).